# OpenLDAP encryption storage Schema

Tags: encryption, passwords, openldap, ssha

I am using OpenLDAP 2.4.38 windows version.
Apache DS for ldap explorer.
Configured password encryption mechanism SSHA in slapd.conf of OpenLDAP.
     password-hash {SSHA}
Now when I change password using JNDI and check in Apache DS it shows password as plaintext.
Is this Apache DS's problem or OpenLDAP is really storing in plaintext even if I configured encryption mechanism as SSHA in OpenLDAP?

Answer (score 1):

I got it worked ultimately. Just updating here in case someone trying in windows version need this. 
Need to add the following line in slapd.conf file. 
include actual-location/ppolicy.schema 
#this is optional for SSHA but mandatory for SHA256 or SHA512 etc.
password-hash {SSHA}
overlay ppolicy
ppolicy_hash_cleartext